# Terra not working (GDAL error 4) new Sonoma 14.0 update

Tags: r, terra

I updated Mac to Sonoma 14.0 a couple of days ago and Terra stopped working. I tried installing the dev version of terra `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')` but had no success.

Edit:

This is the error message after I tried to load a .nc file.

```
Error: [rast] cannot open this file as a SpatRaster: /Users/elocarinista/Research/Weather_HealthPerception/data/tmax.2018.nc
In addition: Warning message:
`/Users/elocarinista/Research/Weather_HealthPerception/data/tmax.2018.nc' not recognized as a supported file format. (GDAL error 4) 
Called from: error(f, x@cpp$getError())
```

BTW, Installing the terra package does not throw any errors, only when I load an .nc file.

Thanks for any help

Comment: *"but had no success"* does not help us to see the problem to help you. Please include all output after `install.packages(..)`, as it tends to include things that should clue us in to some inherent problem (xcode or otherwise)

Comment: You are right. Sorry for that. I have edited my question and added the output.

Comment: Have your tried `<- rast("filename.ncdf", drivers="NETCDF")` where you are specifying the GDAL driver to use, from `?terra::rast details`, and, what does `terra::gdal(warn = NA, drivers = FALSE, lib = 'gdal')` report?

Comment: Thank you, I solve the problem. found out the nc file had no been correctly downloaded. That was the issue.